# finding id name of 5 most frequent value in a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a data which has column name "birth_country"
i executed following code;

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df['birth_country'].value_counts()[:5]
```

output:

```
United States of America     259
United Kingdom               85
Germany                      61
France                       51
Sweden                       29
```

I want my output to be look like;

```
United States of America
United Kingdom
Germany
France
Sweden
```

How to do it?

Like;

```
df['birth_country'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

gives output:

```
United States of America
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For series by `index` values use:

```
pd.Series(df['birth_country'].value_counts()[:5].index)
```

Comment: It gives dublicate result;
United States of America    United States of America

United Kingdom                        United Kingdom
kinda like this

Comment: @def__init__ - Answer was EDITed